# Android Studio + Artifactory

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have library project, developed on Android Studio 1.3.0 and deployed to Artifactory Open Source Local Repository (3.5)

But when I try to load it in application project, no classes were found

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.my:my-library:2.1.0'
}
```

Refresh dependencies doesn't help

```
gradle --refresh-dependencies
```

In local cache directory **/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.my/my-library/2.1.0** jar file exist

Answer (score 7):

You have to add the repository to the repositories closure in you project gradle file:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url artifactoryUrl
    }
}
```

Where artifactoryUrl could be something like

```
"http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local"
```

Comment: Yes, i add it. Apparently it was some compile mistakes in project, after fix, dependency classes was added to project